# Defining the main form to appear

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, authentication

I have 2 Forms: an authentication Form and a menu Form.
Obviously, I want the auth Form to appear first, but the menu Form is the one that appears first instead. I tried this piece of code but it didn't work.

This code actually shows the 2 Forms at the same time.
(**`type`** is a global string initialized with "")

```
Private Sub FormMenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If type = "" Then
        Me.Hide()
        Formauthentification.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which Form *appears* first is defined in the Project properties (`Project -> Properties -> Application -> Startup form`). I suggest you also select `Shutdown mode -> When last form closes` if it's not already set. You can then make your `Formauthentification` the startup Form.

Comment: @jimi and that should be posted as an answer, then other people don't waste time coming in here thinking the problem is unaddressed when in fact it has been solved. Posting comments that answer questions is thus quite inconsiderate towards your peers; please consider not doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jimi's comment:

> Which Form appears first is defined in the Project properties (`Project -> Properties -> Application -> Startup form`).
>   I suggest you also select `Shutdown mode -> When last form closes` if it's not already set. You can then make your Formauthentification the startup Form